# Is there a Solidify Extrude function?

Tags: modeling, mesh

The normal Extrude works like this: take selected geometry and move to another place. But I need something that leaves the selected geometry where it is and duplicates it.

I noticed that when you extrude a simple plane it generates a cube. How do I achieve that but just with a larger pool of polygons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>*> Solidify*:

[image]

Note that in many cases (including the example in the gif), this will probably result in [non-manifold geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry).